# Which case is used for titles?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In an article from G. Peano,

> §1. Casus
>
> §2. Genere masculino, feminino et neutro
>
> §3. Numero singulare et plurale

I wonder if *casus* should be understood as singular or as plural.
As far as I know it belongs to the 4th declension, I guess the case is nominative so I have no way to distinguish between "The case" and "The cases". Maybe the other titles will help.

Comment: As you say *casus* could be either singular or plural. *Genere,* 'gender,' and *Numero* 'number,' although Singular are not in the Nominative. I  personally don't think your question can be answered.

Comment: Thank you but I don't get "although Singular are not in the Nominative".

Comment: In a list of titles you might expect all to be Nominative singular: *Casus, Genus, Numerus.*  Or else all nom plural *Casus, Genera, Numeri.*  Or else all Ablative singular: *Casu, Numero, Genere.*  No consistency. So it is up to you.

Comment: Please make it an answer so that I close the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the (unidentified) article by Peano is in Italian. In no. 2 and 3 the title is a mixture of Latin and Italian. Actually only "et" is Latin.

Edit: The correct answer is in my comment below.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/latinosineflexio/de-latino-sine-flexione-1903

Comment: @Blincer. Thank you for the link. This is not Latin, nor is it Italian. It is "Latino sine flexione", an artificial language invented by Peano.

Comment: Yes I knew it was the topic but I did not notice he uses the lang in the article.

Answer (score 1):

As you say *casŭs, casūs* could be either singular or plural Nominative.

Genere, 'gender,' and Numero 'number,' although both Singular are not in the Nominative. I personally don't think your question can be answered.

In a list of titles you might expect all to be Nominative singular:

> Casus, Genus, Numerus.

Or else all nom plural

> Casūs, Genera, Numeri.

Or else all Ablative singular:

> Casu, Numero, Genere.

There is no consistency. So it is up to you.

However, [in this paper](https://sites.google.com/site/latinosineflexio/de-latino-sine-flexione-1903), when *'casus,'* even without a macron, occurs in the next two sentences, it is definitely plural. In context *'casus'*  sounds better translated as plural or implying Case in general.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having it in an answer:

This article seems to be *De Latino sine Flexione*, where Peano proposes using Latin as the international language, but without any inflections. Nouns, for example, generally go in the ablative singular (which looks the closest to the Romance forms).

The article starts out in proper Classical Latin, so *casūs* is plural: "The Cases". But as it goes on, it drops more and more of the inflections: *genere* is also plural ("The Genders"), but it's been given an ablative singular ending.